# How can I create a webpack application with some js libs but does not include it on pack but use its CDN?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I Want to pack a js web application that use several js libs (like vuejs, numeraljs, momentjs) and some CSS packs (like bootstrap and some webkits). Today my webpack starts from a `index.js` entry point and add everything onto a single JS `main.min.js`.

I would like to only pack my own application files to the and download the other dependencies from a CDN URL.

The problem is, when I import a reference (`import Vue from 'vue'`) the webpack packs the lib inside the `main.min.js` file

How can I create an application, import references from a lib (like vue) without packing everything together  ?

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/